# For loop in java to find a player object in an array of players

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am learning java, and I am working on loops now. I have written this code:

```
players[0] = new Player(1, "Paul", "Point Guard");
players[1] = new Player(24, "Bryant", "Shooting Guard");
players[2] = new Player (6, "James", "Small Foward");
players[3] = new Player (21, "Duncan", "Power Foward");
players[4] = new Player (12, "Howard", "Center"); 
players[5] = new Player (6, "Erving", "Small Foward");


public String name()
{   
    int number = readNumber(); // read in the number
    String s = "";
    for(Player player: players){
        // check if input number match with any number of the players
        if(player.numberMatches(number))        
            s += player.getName() + " ";
        else s = error();
    }
    return s;
}
```

the error() method is just returning a "No player has this number"
I have two players in my array players that have the same number; when I call name() it returns "No Player has this nameErving" 
I have tried to delete the else statement and all works fine. Why?
Can anybody help me please?

Comment: We will need to see the Player code as well as the declaration of the method: readNumber().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are re-assigning `s` every time a player's number does not match the given number.

This is logically incorrect, and effectively erases all the players that have been found, every time a player's number does not match. Try something like this instead.

```
public String name()
{   
    int number = readNumber(); // read in the number
    String s = "";
    for(Player player : players){
        // check if input number match with any number of the players
        if(player.numberMatches(number))        
            s += player.getName() + " ";
    }
    return s.equals("") ? error() : s;
}
```

Comment: Yes of course!! Thank you, that makes perfectly sense!! Your solution is working just fine. Now I have to figure out what your return statement means.. I haven't learned that syntax yet, but thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure. It's called the "ternary operator" because it takes three operands. `a ? b : c` means if a is true return b, else return c. This works because if no players are found, then `s.equals("")` is true, so the ternary operator returns `error()`.